# How to load addtional parameter in CMake?

Tags: makefile, cmake

I want to build a project @local dictionary.

And in 'CMakeLists.txt' the project A want to find another library B using 'FIND_PACKAGE' command.

The problem is that library B can be found in system directory while I rebuild it @ my local directory, so how can I control that case by inputting a additional parameter when typing 'cmake .'?

Answer (score 1):

You can give specify variable values using CMake's [-D command line option](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#opt%3a-Dvar%3atypevalue).

Note that the variable in question has to be stored in the cache for this to work, as the command line simply sets a cache entry and local variables hide cache variables of the same name.

```
cmake -DMY_AWESOME_VARIABLE=Foo <path_to_source>
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
 [...]
# set a default value that will be used if no option is given on the command line
set(MY_AWESOME_VARIABLE "Default value" CACHE STRING "")
# this line will output the current value from cache; so either the default
# value or whatever was given last on the command line
message(${MY_AWESOME_VARIABLE})
# local variables hide cache entry, so the next message will always print "Local"
set(MY_AWESOME_VARIABLE "Local")
message(${MY_AWESOME_VARIABLE})
```

Answer (score 0):

you could temporarily change the PATH environment variable to only your local bin aud or usr...  by running cmake with:

```
PATH=~/bin:~/usr:~/usr/bin cmake
```

But then you have to put all the required executables in that/those folders.